# Dynamic menu which depends on the security group context in a webpart of SharePoint online Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, quick-launch, quick-links

There is a menu on the left side of **SharePoint online modern experience** that shows all the lists that a person member of. Is there a way to show the left menu as a web part?

If not, is there a way to show all the lists that a person member of in a web part (of course without showing them all the lists in the site) by hyperlinks?

I can add all the lists of my sites through individual hyperlinks but do not know how to hide irrelevant hyperlinks to a user based on its security group settings (the same way the left menu works)

Something like this:

[image]

Please let me know if my question needs clarification.

I am trying to implement the solution suggested by Ganesh but the target audience cannot find security groups that I have created.

Security groups are as follows:

[image]

and the target audience filter:

[image]

another group:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Audience Targeting** feature in Quick links web part to show/hide links based on user groups (AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups) similar to audience targeting in left navigation (quick launch).

Check below article for detailed steps about enabling audience targeting on quick links web part & setting set the target audiences for each link:

[Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)

---

**Note**: Currently you can only use Azure AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups to target audiences. If you want to use **SharePoint groups** for audience targeting, [vote on this UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42712238-allow-using-sharepoint-groups-to-target-audiences).

---

**Update from comments**:

SharePoint groups are not supported in audience targeting (limitation by Microsoft).

If you want to show links based on SharePoint group membership, you have to develop custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) web part as this is not possible using out of the box quick links web part.

Check below SPFx web part samples developed by community members which might help you to get started with:

1. [React Links web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-links)
2. [Custom Links web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custom-links)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is the thing that I am looking for, I have tested it but seems does not load security groups. I have added new screentshots, could you please have a look and advise,

Comment: Azure Active Directory groups (including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported with the exception of AAD dynamic groups. AAD dynamic groups will be supported some time in 2021. Check more information related to audience targeting, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

Comment: I think you are trying to use SharePoint groups in audience targeting which is not supported. check **Note** in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it is not supported, Since this does not answer my question, I cannot accept the answer but as a token of appreciation, I will upvote ur answer.

Comment: Yes, SP groups are not supported (limitation by Microsoft). If you want to show links based on SP group membership, you have to develop custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) web part as this is not possible using out of the box web part. Check [this](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custom-links) & [this](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-links) web parts which might help you to get started with. This might answer your question now.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, great, those links seem the things that I am after,